# How to assign different generic classes to same variable

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I know this question has probably been asked many times and my title probably needs some help so feel free to close this question after pointing me to a duplicate... just not sure how to properly search for the answer at the moment.

I've got a situation where a variable may need to hold and instance of `ISolrOperations<Class1>` or it may need to hold an instance of `ISolrOperations<Class2>`. The problem is that there is no base version of the interface and so there's no class I can define the variable as (other than object, which obviously has no knowledge of `ISolrOperations<T>`'s methods) to be able to hold either class.

So the only solutions I know of are either a) Do an if/else statement where I do everything I need with `ISolrOperations<Class1>` in one block and everything I need in `ISolrOperations<Class2>` in the other block even though each block will basically contain duplicate code. Or b) I could make the variable dynamic and just lose some compile time validation of my code.

I'm trying to think if there is some way I can create a generic wrapper class that has a non-generic base. And maybe the base has to treat it as an object but uses reflection... but them I'm like screw it; if I have to go through that trouble may as well just use the dynamic keyword.

Is there a more "proper" design pattern to handle this scenario? Or is my choice basically between dynamic or writing a lot of code just to make myself feel like I'm doing it "right" when dynamic is really the most practical solution?

Edit: Actually I'm not sure if dynamic would solve this problem :/

Edit 2: Nope... other code uses lambdas with the variable which requires casting it which I obviously don't know what to cast to at compile time so that won't work.

Comment: Could you create base non generic interface `ISolrOperations` which will be implemented also by generic one... then you can kind a route normal calls to generic ones... or idea to create decorator...

Comment: I wish. It's from a 3rd party dll though. I'm mean it's open source so theoretically I could but I definitely ain't got time for that.

Comment: Plus one for the thought though cause it's the 1st thing I'd do (and have done in the past) with my own code.

Comment: I see. What are the methods of the `interface`?

Comment: Only one I'm interested in is "Query"

Comment: Does `Query` method returns instance or collection of Class1 or Class2? Could you modify Class1 or Class2?

Comment: Query returns `SolrQueryResults<T>`. I can modify Class1/2. I tried making them both inherit from a common base class but that doesn't help when they have to be the generic parameter of another type unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not sure, this approach might help. This approach uses **adapter pattern**.

```
public interface ISolrOperations<T> 
{
    SqlQuery<T> Execute();
}

public interface ISolrOperationsAdapter
{
    IEnumerable<Base> Execute();
}

//Idealy you have interfaces
public class Base { }
public class Class1 : Base { }
public class Class2 : Base { }  

public abstract class SolrOperationsAdapter : ISolrOperationsAdapter
{
    protected SolrOperationsAdapter()
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Base> Execute()
    {
        return ExecuteImpl();
    }

    protected abstract IEnumerable<Base> ExecuteImpl();
}


public class GenericSolrOperationsAdapter<T> : SolrOperationsAdapter
{
    private readonly ISolrOperations<T> _solrOperations;

    public static ISolrOperationsAdapter From(ISolrOperations<T> solrOperations)
    {
        return new GenericSolrOperationsAdapter<T>(solrOperations);
    }

    protected GenericSolrOperationsAdapter(ISolrOperations<T> solrOperations)
        : base()
    {
        _solrOperations = solrOperations;
    }

    //If you define interfaces you can return return IEnumerable<IInterface>
    protected override IEnumerable<Base> ExecuteImpl()
    {
        //here you can somehow convert result of query to your types(Class1, Class2 or some interface behind)
        return _solrOperations.Execute().ConvertTo<IEnumerable<Base>>();
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
ISolrOperations<Class1> solrOperations = new SolrOperationsImplementation()
ISolrOperationsAdapter adapter = GenericSolrOperationsAdapter<Class1>.From(solrOperations);
IEnumerable<Base> result = adapter.Execute();
```

Comment: hmm... probably won't get to try this tonight but I'll let you know this weekend if this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the class in a generic adapter class that implements the required interface.

This is called the adapter pattern in case you want to search for examples of it.

Example of a generic adapter:

```
public class SomeGenericInterfaceAdapter<T> : INonGenericInterface
{
    private IGenericInterface<T> _someGenericInterface;
    public SomeGenericInterfaceAdapter(IGenericInterface<T> someGenericInterface)
    {
        _someGenericInterface = someGenericInterface;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _someGenericInterface.SomeMethod();
    }
}

public interface INonGenericInterface
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public interface IGenericInterface<T>
{
    void SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: So the example I gave makes it sound like there would just be 2 classes, whereas in real life there are more. And whereas the adapter pattern can work with 2 very different classes... each class in my case is basically the same already. I mean I know it's technically different because each generic class is different but still. Ugh... just messy no matter how I do it I guess.

Comment: The adapter class can be generic but the interface it implements doesnt have to be. This should prevent you from having to implement it for every class.

Comment: I have added a example of this.